# Java program operating differently when run from JButton click

Tags: java, jbutton

I have a java program called 'Program Selector' that uses JButtons on a JPanel to allow a user to pick a Java program they want to run. (Each button runs a different program)

The programs I want to run produce .txt or excel files as outputs among doing some other things. The Programs work perfectly fine when I run the .jar directly from a mouse click.. all the output .txt files are generated etc.

However my problem is that when I try to run the programs through the 'Program Selector' with the JButton click the programs launch and function as they should in every was except they don't seem to be able to create the .txt or excel output files as they do when run directly from a mouse click...

Here is the code used to run the selected programs on the button click:

```
        programButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent arg0) -> {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("../../directory/program.jar")); 
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

(There are 4 buttons on the Program selector in total, all run their target .jar in the exact same way as above)

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

This is my first question posted here so if I should add more of the code from the program let me know.

Comment: what exactly do you think the System.exit(1); does?

Comment: I suspect the files are been created, but just not where you think should be getting created.  It's possible they are getting created in the same working directory of the "selector" program

Comment: Doesn't the `System.exit(x)` terminate the currently running JVM? If yes, the error could be calling a jar and shutting down the JVM directly after the call...

Comment: @Stultuske I have it there to close the 'Program Selector' once a button has been clicked. I have tried removing it but the issue still remains.

Comment: @Hexicidal it closes your entire JVM, that includes the thread you want to be writing to file(s)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your help, you're right it was trying to save them in the Program Selector directory, I created a target folder with the correct name and the output files are being generated in it now!

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for your help, the System.exit(x) wasn't the immediate issue but I seen now how it wont work as a way to close just the Program Selector without also closing everything else. Thank you!

Comment: @Stultuske Actualky, given the way open works, it’s probably executing another instance of a jvm